# Subprocess.call for cmd

Tags: python

I have the following command that works in the shell:

```
$ pv itunes20140910.tbz | sudo tar xpj -C /tmp
```

However, when I try and do it in python, it doesn't work:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex
>>> cmd=shlex.split('pv itunes20140910.tbz | sudo tar xpj -C /tmp')
>>> subprocess.call(cmd)
pv: invalid option -- 'C'
Try `pv --help' for more information.
1
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what would be the correct command to run in python?

Comment: Don't use `shlex.split`. Just pass the string directly in.

Comment: You may run into issues because you're using `sudo` here, which is likely to bring up a password prompt.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can't pass a string unless you use `shell=True`.

Comment: @dano, I wouldn't actually expect that to be a problem here -- stdin and stdout aren't being reattached, so they should still go to the TTY, so sudo should still be able to get a handle to prompt with.

Comment: @dano, untrue; `shell=True` is set by default if one passes a string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, it would be a problem if this script is ever intended to be run without the user being there to type in the password. It may not matter to the OP if he/she is expecting to be there to type it in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No it's not. Try `subprocess.call("ls /")` for yourself. It will fail, saying something about no such file/directory.

Comment: @dano, ...heh; I stand corrected. Surprised I've had that wrong in my head for so many years... but then, I always, _always_ pass an array in to `subprocess` calls and avoid shell invocation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy :). In your defense, the behavior with lists vs. strings with `shell=True` vs.`shell=False` is pretty confusing. The docs need several paragraphs to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didn't have the net effect of what I was looking for (the progress bar), though the command would run without error. Here is what worked for me:

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('pv /tmp/itunes20140910.tbz'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #Set up the echo command and direct the output to a pipe
>>> subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('sudo tar xpj -C /tmp'), stdin=p1.stdout) #send p1's output to p2
```

Comment: Why pass `subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('some string'))` rather than just `subprocess.Popen(['some', 'string'])`? The latter is more robust, since it doesn't require your strings to be properly escaped for shlex's interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shell=True` argument. Otherwise `|` cannot be interpreted.

```
subprocess.call('pv itunes20140910.tbz | sudo tar xpj -C /tmp', shell=True)
```